# Efficient select with restrictions on two, big joined tables

Tags: sql, db2

I have two huge tables in a DB2-Database. I have adapted the real-names to another problem to highlight the issue and obfuscate the real use case.

```
CREATE TABLE Author (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name vargraphic(32) NOT NULL,
    country vargraphic(32) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE Book(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    title vargraphic(32) NOT NULL,
    authorId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Author(id),
    releaseYear Integer NOT NULL)
```

Both tables get so big, that doing a full-table scan is not feasible on either of them.

Here I want to find the first 10 books released in 2017, sorted by their title

```
SELECT b.title, b.authorId
FROM Book b 
WHERE b.RELEASEYEAR = 2017
ORDER BY b.TITLE
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

To speed it up I create an index

```
CREATE INDEX itest1 ON BOOK (releaseYear, title, id, authorid);
```

With this index an index-only-scan is done and the query is very fast.

Now I want to restrict the result to only those books written by american authors.

```
SELECT b.title, b.authorId
FROM Book b 
JOIN Author a ON (a.id = b.authorId) 
WHERE b.RELEASEYEAR = 2017
AND a.COUNTRY = 'USA'
ORDER BY b.TITLE
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

I try to speed this query up as well by adding more indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX itest3 ON AUTHOR (id, country);
CREATE INDEX itest4 ON AUTHOR (country, id);
```

Even tough indexe-only-scan are used, the performance is not close the the one the previous statement had.

EXPLAIN PLAN tells me that after doing an index scan on both tables an expensive Nested-Loop-Join is done. It seems that the first index is used for finding *books from 2017, ordered by title* and the second is used for *authors by country*. But if each of those subsets is still very big, creating intersection takes a long time.

What I kind of would like to do is avoid the nested-loop, by having a single index that spans two tables.

```
CREATE INDEX two_table_index ON Book b JOIN Author a (a.country, b.releaseYear, b.title)
```

But this is not possible it seems. Is there another way to effectively run the second query on very big tables?

Comment: Don't know about DB2, but it often works well for me to not do a join and instead say `where authorId in (select id from author where country='USA')`. Another option is to denormalize and also keep the authorCountry field in the books table..

Comment: Index named itest4 seems to be a good solution, you don't even go to database table to read data. All you need is in the index itself. But since you have another table you cannot wait the same performance especially if the USA authors are the major part of the authors

Comment: Avoid words such as huge and big because they are meaningless. Give round figures instead to the nearest 10-million or billions etc. Always state your Db2 server operating-system and Db2 version. Are the tables range-partitioned or distributed-by-hash? Are they compressed?  When creating indexes that have multiple columns, it's best to order the columns by highest selectivity first. Collect suitable  runstats on each index after creation.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you'd get better using only indexes, if you really want this query to be really fast, you'd have to replicate the country into the book table, and then use two indexes :

index one author(id) (key i guess ?)

index two book(releaseyear,authorcountry,title)

Comment: I dont like breaking the second normal form, as this will mean i need to keep these extra column in Book updated when author changes. However I am running out of options so this approach is what I am considering to try next. I will report back with results.

Answer (score 1):

> EXPLAIN PLAN tells me that after doing an index scan on both tables an expensive Nested-Loop-Join is done. It seems that the first index is used for finding books from 2017, ordered by title and the second is used for authors by country. But if each of those subsets is still very big, creating intersection takes a long time.

Of course that's what it's doing; that's all the indices you have allow it to do.

The problem, essentially, is the only index you have on `Book` doesn't help it narrow down authors any until during or after the sorting step; `title` is a dead column in the index.  Usually filtering conditions should come first in an index, and a join counts as one.

Try one (or more) of the following indices:

```
-- More generally applicable
BOOK (authorId, releaseYear, title)
-- This one might help more for this query
BOOK (releaseYear, authorId, title)
-- Won't help at all for this query, but probably useful for others
BOOK (authorId, title)
```

As a side note: most of the time optimizers will spit out recommended indices for queries, does it list any?

Comment: The "optimizer" I am using is the Tool "Aqua-Data-Studio". It does not show me any suggested indexes. The reason I use that tool is that was the only way for me to get a an EXPLAIN to work at all. While on postgres I would just write "EXPLAIN ANALYZE <query>", on db2 I need to first create some tables, then explain analyze and then WRITE A SCRIPT/BIG QUERY to actually look at the results. Before I tried the approach shown here http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/db2/getting-an-execution-plan but the final query always gives me an empty result. If you know a good way, let me know

Comment: Sorry, the optimizer is a specific step during query execution.  It's how the system knows it can use any indices at all.  Probably, I'm too used to the iSeries and its tools, which wouldn't help you on LUW.  As for not getting results, it may be that your statement is generating an error.  You could possibly also try turning on monitoring and get the plan that way.